# JQUERY $(this).next issue

Tags: jquery, this

Hi everybody I know this question has already been asked few times, but I am stuck with this issue.
I have the following lines of code:

```
<tr>
                <td>Nome Hw:</td>
                <td><INPUT class="clickableElement" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="nomeHw" size="50" value="<?php echo $rowHWCFG['NOMEHARDWARE']; ?>" readonly></td>

                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Quantit&agrave;</td>
                <td class="hardwareQuantity"><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="versione" size="20" value="<?php echo $rowHWCFG['QUANTITAHARDWARE']; ?>" readonly></td>
                <td >Valida dal</td>
                <td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="validaDalHw" size="15" value="<?php echo $rowHWCFG['VALIDADALHW']; ?>" readonly>
                </td>
                <td >Valida al</td>
                <td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="validaAlHw" size="15" value="<?php echo $rowHWCFG['VALIDAALHW']; ?>" readonly></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
```

Whit Jquery I have used the ".bind" function to bind the "click event" on the first input (don't mind about the selector *.floatingMenuTable:eq(2)*:

```
$('.floatingMenuTable:eq(2) input.clickableElement').bind("click", function() {

                    var nome_HW = $(this).val();

                    var quantita_HW = $(this).parent().find('.versione').val();

                    alert("Nome Hw:" + nome_HW + " Quantita:" + quantita_HW);
                    //showEditDetailItemMenu(this,'edit',nome_HW,quantita_HW);
            });
```

Using this code I can get the value of "nome_HW" but it does not work to get the value of the 2nd input named "quantitaHW". So please can someone help me to write the right function? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like the html code you posted is not related to the js posted. Please revise your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using the followig instruction:

```
// Edit the Hw Config
$('.floatingMenuTable:eq(2) input.clickableElement').bind("click", function() 
{

  var nome_HW = $(this).val();

  var quantita_HW = $(this).parent().siblings('td.hardwareQuantity').find('input').val();

  alert("Nome Hw:" + nome_HW + " Quantita:" + quantita_HW);

});
```

What I can suggest from my experience is DRAWING ON A PAPER THE ELEMENT $(this) Clicked, and creating the target Element drawing all the DOM Elements required to go FROM A to B.
So in my example:

```
$(this) -> click on the input field with name attribute: "nomeHw" and with class: "clickableElement"

parent() -> Move inside the Dom selecting the "td" element that contains the input field "nomeHw"

siblings('td.hardwareQuantity') -> move to the sibling with classname "hardwareQuantity" 

find('input') -> find the input close to that td with classname "hardwareQuantity"
```

Answer (score 0):

i have alter some php statement to run in this snippet.value is displayed in alert now as you have expected.

please correct the jquery selector for class and id inside the click function.

```js
$('input').bind("click", function() {

                    var nome_HW = $(this).val();

                    var quantita_HW = $(this).parent().find('#nomeHw').val();

                    alert("Nome Hw:" + nome_HW + " Quantita:" + quantita_HW);
                    //showEditDetailItemMenu(this,'edit',nome_HW,quantita_HW);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
              <label for="nomeHw">Nome HW:</label>
              <select id="nomeHw"  name="nomeHw" onchange="" required>
              <option>1</option>
              </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;

              <label for="quantitaHW">Quantità</label>
              <input class="quantitaHW" id="quantitaHW" name="quantitaHW" type="text" value="text" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;

            </p>
```

Comment: I solved using the followig instruction:

var quantita_HW = $(this).parent().siblings('td.hardwareQuantity').find('input').val();

All I needed was just to move properly inside the DOM :D

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Give each input, select, etc. a class they all share (ex. `.control`). Delegate the change event to the `<form>` tag (You should have one)(ex. `#main`). `.map()` the values out.

---

```js
/*
When a user enters or changes any value of any .control...
an array of numbers and strings is returned.
*/
$('#main').on("change", function(event) {
  var arr = $('.control').map(function(idx, obj) {
    return Number($(this).val()) || $(this).val();
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.toArray()));
  return arr;
});
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <fieldset>

    <legend>HW</legend>

    <label for="nameHW">Name: </label>
    <select id="nameHW" name="nameHW" class='control' required>
      <option value=''>Pick</option>
      <option value='H'>H</option>
      <option value='W'>W</option>
      <option value='HW'>HW</option>
    </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;

    <label for="qtyHW">Quantity: </label>
    <input id="qtyHW" name="qtyHW" class='control' type="number" value="0" min='0' max='99'>

  </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok I will give it a try! :)